# Python, remove all elements in a list of index > n

Tags: python, indexing

Say I have a list:

```
myList = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
```

Now, say i have a user input the index at which they want to cut the list off. How would I remove all the elements in the list with index greater than the inputted value, or re-create a list with new boundaries?

e.g)

```
x = input('Please enter index of last value in new list')
# say inputted value for x is 3
# I want to end the list at index 3 (i.e the new list will be [1,2,3,4])
```

What would be the fastest way to obtain my goal?

Comment: Have you tried anything?... Please share what you have tried

Comment: myList[:] = myList[:int(x)]

Comment: "How would I use list comprehension paired with the list.remove() python function" - pairing those things is essentially always a terrible idea, and neither of those tools is useful for your task.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
myList = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
x = input('Please enter index of last value in new list')
myList = myList[0:x+1]
print myList
```

Comment: It seems that the OP needs to remove some elements from the original list, not create a new one.

Comment: If you want to modify the original list: `myList[:] = myList[0:x+1]`

Comment: @PeterWood: Or `del myList[x+1:]`, which is probably faster.

Comment: @user2357112 I've tried timing it and you're right. It seems constant time, and much faster.

Comment: @PeterWood: It's not constant time, but it has the major advantage that it only needs to look at index x+1 and up instead of the whole list.